# AVCapturedevice returns nil when set

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to set up 2 AVCapturedevices: in particular frontCamera and backCamera in the following way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setCaptureSession()
    setupDevice()
    setUpInputOutput() 
}
```

in viewDidLoad I'm calling this functions that respectively do this:

```
func setCaptureSession(){
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
}

func setupDevice(){
    frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)
    backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    currentCamera = backCamera
}
```

Even-tough I think I set up the back camera correctly when I run the app I get the error in this function:

```
func setUpInputOutput(){
    do{
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
    }catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Basically when I try to setup AVCapturedeviceInput with device **currentCamera** I receive an error because currentCamera is nil.
I don't understand why it is nil and what I can do to solve this problem.

I use Xcode 11 with Swift 4.

Comment: This is odd indeed. Could you maybe create a `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession` to check if cameras you are trying to use are available?

Comment: I tried to do it but no camera device is detected... I don't know why is that, maybe because I'm using the simulator and not the actual camera of the device? @FrankSchlegel

Comment: Yes, that’s it. Simulator doesn’t support camera capture at all. You have to test on device.

Comment: Ok thanks so much man, Can I ask you if I need to pay a developer subscription in order to test my app on my device?

Comment: You don’t. You just have to register at developer.apple.com.

Comment: Thank you so much! @FrankSchlegel